# Failed to fetch packages (forbidden)

Tags: updates, repository, software-sources

I'm fairly new to Linux so I'm still trying to figure this out.

Running `apt-get update`, I get a bunch of repository errors

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main/amd64 amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main/amd64 i386 Packages
  403  Forbidden
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main/amd64 Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Fetched 72 B in 15s (4 B/s)
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/amd64/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/amd64/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/updates/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/updates/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Primarily I am trying to install basic Intel graphics drivers.

I've been playing around with my sources.list but so far I've been unsuccessful.

This is my current `sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main multiverse
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates/ubuntu trusty/main amd64
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

All the online help I've found so far tends to be old and outdated.

Thanks in advance for the help

ADDED INFORMATION

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fossfreedom-packagefixes-trusty.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/fossfreedom-packagefixes-trusty.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/fossfreedom/packagefixes/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ffmpeg-3-trusty.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ffmpeg-3-trusty.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ffmpeg-3-trusty.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/ffmpeg-3/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kirillshkrogalev-ffmpeg-next-trusty.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kirillshkrogalev-ffmpeg-next-trusty.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/obsproject-obs-studio-trusty.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/obsproject-obs-studio-trusty.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf-graphics-drivers-trusty.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf-graphics-drivers-trusty.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-x-swat-ppa-trusty.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-x-swat-ppa-trusty.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-x-swat-updates-trusty.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/updates/ubuntu trusty main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-x-swat-updates-trusty.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/updates/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: You have two problems: First and most important, disable the PPA. Second, [fix the GPG error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey).

Comment: Please add the output of `fgrep '' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` to your question.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks, I've fixed the GPG error. When you say disable the PPA, do you mean comment it out in the sources.list file?

Comment: Yes, that's the right way to disable a source.